# Find the first staring Point of the circular tour that allows to visits all petrol pumps

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I'm trying to solve the following [HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/truck-tour/problem) (similar problem also can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-tour-that-visits-all-stations/)).

> **Truck Tour**
>
> Suppose there is a circle. There are petrol pumps on that circle.
> Petrol pumps are numbered from `0` to `N` (both inclusive).
>
> You have *two pieces of information* corresponding to
> each of the petrol pump:
>
> - the **amount of petrol** that particular
>   petrol pump will give,
> - the **distance** from that petrol pump to
>   the next petrol pump.
>
> Initially, you have a **tank** of **infinite capacity** carrying no petrol.
> You can start the tour at any of the petrol pumps.
>
> Calculate the first
> point from where the truck will be able to complete the circle.
> Consider that the truck will stop at each of the petrol pumps. The
> truck will move one kilometer for each litre of the petrol.

The input of the method is a matrix `Nx2` represented as a nested list `List<List<Integer>>`, where `N` is the number of petrol pumps (size of the list).

Each of the pumps (inner list `List<Integer>`) has `2` elements that correspond to the *amount of petrol the pump gives* and the *amount of petrol required* to reach the next pump (*see detailed description in the links above*).

We need to find the index of the first pump that would allow to visit all `N` petrol pumps in a circular fashion.

My code seems to be fine, but Hackerrank says that it fails in some situations. What am I missing here?

```
public static int truckTour(List<List<Integer>> petrolpumps) {
    
    long tank;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < petrolpumps.size(); i++){
        if(petrolpumps.get(i).get(0) >= petrolpumps.get(i).get(1)){
           
            tank = (petrolpumps.get(i).get(0) - petrolpumps.get(i).get(1));
            
            boolean good = true;
            
            for(int j = 0; j < petrolpumps.size(); j++){
                int index = j + i;
                
                if(index > (petrolpumps.size() - 1))
                    index = index % petrolpumps.size();
                
                tank += (petrolpumps.get(index).get(0) - petrolpumps.get(index).get(1));
                
                if(tank < 0){
                    good = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if(good)
                return i;
        }
    }
         
    System.out.println("=/");
    return -1; 

}
```

Comment: It is the same problem... anyway... I will put their link too.

Comment: It is an algorithm... I can ask why it has a problem here. I like StackOverflow =).

Comment: I dont know... they don´t offer it... it is locked. The input that is not locked is correct.

Comment: It starts the loop if petrolpumps.get(i).get(0) >= petrolpumps.get(i).get(1) ... tank can be negative at the loop start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is rooted in the initialization of the `tank` variable. You double-count the amount of petrol provided by the pump `i` - it gets added to the `tank` first while initializing the `tank` and second time in the inner `for`-loop when `j=0`. For that reason, you're getting incorrect results.

To fix it, instead of this line:

```
tank = (petrolpumps.get(i).get(0) - petrolpumps.get(i).get(1));
```

Simply initialize the `tank` to zero. And you can also remove the declaration `tank` before the outer `for`-loop, to confine this variable to a more narrow scope (which is a good practice).

```
long tank = 0;
```

This fix is sufficient to pass all the test cases on *HackerRank*.

There are also a few changes can be done to make the solution more readable and a bit more concise.

I would rather use `if (conditionIsNotMet) continue;` then `if (conditionIsMet) { doStuff }` to reduce the level of nesting.

And since we can't use the index of the inner `for`-loop as is, but instead have to perform some extra actions with it (check if the size exceeded, then apply modulo `%`) I would prefer using `while` loop.

That's how it can be done (*this solution is tested as well*):

```
public static int truckTour(List<List<Integer>> petrolpumps) {
    
    final int size = petrolpumps.size();
    
    for (int start = 0; start < size; start++) {
        if (petrolpumps.get(start).get(0) < petrolpumps.get(start).get(1)) continue;
        
        long tank = 0;
        int position = start;
        int pumpCount = 0;
        
        while (true) {
            if (pumpCount == size) return start; // all pumps has been visited
            if (tank < 0) break;                 // not enough petrol to move further

            tank += petrolpumps.get(position % size).get(0) - petrolpumps.get(position % size).get(1);
            
            position++;
            pumpCount++;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```